# Data Binding inside an .append with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I used this code (http://jsfiddle.net/ftfish/KyEr3/) to create a form, but I have an input with ng-model set to "value" and I need to print that value with {{ }} on that TD:

`angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-table')).append("&lttd&gt;{{value}}&lt;/td&gt;");`

I made this way because I need to print on screen the HTML code (that's why I use `&lt;`instead of <). But the {{value}} don't work with that.

Anyone know how can I get this working? I thought to transform the value of the ng-model in a variable (scope.value), but I'm not expert on AngularJS to achieve that.

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle with what you have so far and show what's missing there? It's easier to resolve the issue that way.

Comment: Unfortunately is a intern project, so it's not safe to post it on public. But I will try to share part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage) to make angular process the templates and directives in your new element:

```
$compile(newElement)(scope);
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.run(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  $rootScope.value = 123;
  var newElem = document.createTextNode("<td>{{value}}</td>");
  document.getElementById('target').appendChild(newElem);
  // important part:
  $compile(newElem)($rootScope);
  $rootScope.$apply();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" id="target"></div>
```

Although if you're just adding similar elements with different data you might just want to use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: I tried to use &compile, but it seems to not be able to work with two &compile under the same function. For example:

`geradorTable.directive("addbuttons", function($compile){
 return function(scope, element, attrs){
  element.bind("click", function(){
   scope.count++;
   angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-first')).append($compile("<p>First Value</p>")(scope));
   angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-table-first')).append(&compile("<p>Test</p>")(scope));
   scope.countresultado = 0;
  });
 };
});`

Comment: If I remove the seconds "angular.element" is works, but I need to add content to those two DIV with the same click.

Comment: Looks like a typo, `&compile` -> `$compile`

Comment: Ow, that's true. Well, now it print both code, but I still can't print "&gt;" instead of <

Comment: @euDennis, I think you'll need to escape "&gt;" before Angular can print it properly.

Comment: The problem is: I need the user to have access to the source of the printed content. The user will fill in the form and the result will be the table, and that why I'm using &gt; instead of <